# Proof that exactness is a local property

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

I know that, **if $M$ is a $R$-module, $M$ is $0$ if and only if $M_p$ is $0$ for every prime ideal $p\subseteq R$**. So if I have an exact sequence of $R$-modules, $0\to A \xrightarrow f B \xrightarrow g C \to 0$ for example, it seems to me that $$(\text{Ker}g_p)/(\text {Im} f_p)=(\text{Ker}g)_p/(\text {Im} f)_p=(\text{Ker}g/\text {Im} f)_p.$$ So if the identities above are true, the argument written in bold makes obvious that exactness is local. However I'm not very sure about those identities, do they really hold?

Comment: If $S\subseteq R$ is a multiplicative set and $N\subseteq M$ are $R$-modules then it is true that $S^{-1}(M/N)\cong S^{-1}M/S^{-1}N$. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I just want to know if the identities that I wrote are true

Comment: Well, yes. The right equality is just a special case of what I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}\newcommand{\into}{\hookrightarrow}$You haven't mentioned this but you are implicitly using that *localisation is an exact functor*.

In other words, if the sequence
$$0 \to A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C \to 0$$
is exact, then so is
$$0 \to A_{\p} \xrightarrow{f_{\p}} B_{\p} \xrightarrow{g_{\p}} C_{\p} \to 0$$
for every prime $\p$.
(In general, localising at any multiplicative subset preserves exactness, not necessarily at the complement of a prime.)

In particular, this shows you that $$B_{\p}/A_{\p} \cong C_{\p} = (B/A)_{\p}.$$

(In the above, I have naturally associated $A$ with a submodule of $B$ and $C$ with $B/A$. Similarly for the localisations.)

(**Sidenote:** By breaking a general exact sequence into short exact sequences of the form $0 \to \ast \to \ast \to \ast \to 0$, one sees that localisation preserves the exactness of *any* exact sequence.)

---

Now suppose that you have a *complex*
$$A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C.$$ (The above simply means that $g \circ f = 0$.)

This tells you that $\im(f) \subset \ker(g)$. By the previous discussion, we have $$\frac{(\ker(g))_{\p}}{(\im(f))_{\p}} \cong \left(\frac{\ker(g)}{\im(f)}\right)_{\p}.$$

However, there is one small check to be done. We need to show that
$$\frac{((\ker(g))_{\p}}{\im(f))_{\p}} \cong \frac{\ker(g_{\p})}{\im(f_{\p})}.$$

To see this, note that exactness of
$$A \xrightarrow{f} \im(f) \to 0$$
gives us exactness of
$$A_{\p} \xrightarrow{f_{\p}} \im(f)_{\p} \to 0.$$
In other words, the map $f_{\p}$ is onto, i.e., $\im(f_{\p}) = \im(f)_{\p}$.
Similarly, considering $$0 \to \ker(g) \to B \xrightarrow{g} C$$ shows us that $(\ker(g_{\p})) = \ker(g)_{\p}$, as desired.